# I need a yes and no button in my form. If the information is correct and yes is clicked thanks should appear

Tags: php, forms, button

I dont know how to add a yes and no button to my form so that when the user inserts and presses the submit button, the data is the sent back from a server side script and back to the user and the user clicks a yes or no button to approve the information. If yes the program should dispute thanks

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Test1-1</title>
        </head>
        <body>
    <?php

    if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "name")){

    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name");
    print "<p>Hi $name, </p>";
    }

    if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "id")){

    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id");
    print "<span>Your Employee ID is $id</span>";
    }

    if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "office")){

    $office = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "office");
    print "<span>, your office is room $office</span>";
    }

    if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "os")){

    $os = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "os");
    print "<span>, and your OS is $os</span>";
    }

     else {


    //there's no input. Create the form 
    print <<< HERE

    <form action ="" method = "post">
    <fieldset>
    <label>Enter your name</label> 
    <input type = "text"
             name = "name"/><br>
    <label>Employee ID</label> 
    <input type = "text"
             name = "id"/><br>
    <label>Office Room Number</label> 
    <input type = "text"
             name = "office"/><br>
    <label>Oberating System on the Office Computer</label> 
    <input type = "text"
             name = "os"/><br>
    <button type = "submit">
     submit
    </button>
    </fieldset> 
    </form>
    HERE;
    }// end 'value exists' if
    ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you are probably going to want to use ajax so you can send the form data to the server side code, then when it returns update the html so that the user then sees the yes/no button.  From there you will need further ajax code to handle what happens when they click yes/no.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a yes or a no button then you just need simple html
    `<input type="button" value="YES">`
    `<input type="button" value="NO">`